# Setter method giving underscore error when I have a getter method

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, setter, getter

I use setters quite often. This is the code I have for this one:

.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *lastSyncDate;
```

.m:

```
-(void)setLastSyncDate:(NSDate *)lastSyncDate {
    _lastSyncDate = lastSyncDate;

    //Do something
}
```

Then I put in a getter method:

```
-(NSDate *)lastSyncDate {
    //Something happens
    return lastSyncDate;
}
```

And then the `_lastSyncDate` identifier gives out an `unidentified identifier` error.

I'm not sure why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
return _lastSyncDate;
```

in the getter method. By default, the synthesized *instance variables* have a leading underscore
(and you already use that in the setter method).

Also, if you provide *both setter and getter method*, you have to synthesize the
property *explicitly*:

```
@synthesize lastSyncDate = _lastSyncDate;
```

The same would happen if you provide the getter for a read-only property.
The property is synthesized by the compiler only if a
required accessor method is missing.

Comment: The getter method does some other stuff, as will the setter, so doesn't actually return the property directly. But changing it to _lastSyncDate gives the same error anyway.